# Auto-scrolling a PDF on a page basis with Adobe Acrobat Pro XI

Tags: windows-7, pdf, adobe-acrobat, scrolling

Is it possible to auto-scroll a PDF on a page basis with Adobe Acrobat Pro XI with Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate? By page basis I mean I want the PDF to auto-scroll page by page, and not by small increments which is the default behavior when selecting "Automatic Scroll":

[image]

I am aware that I can use some external the programs to take care of that ( e.g. AHK ), but I want to know whether Adobe Acrobat Pro XI has this feature.

Comment: May I ask "why"?

Comment: Going through pdf slides without having to click or having to cut pdf into one image per page.

Comment: Is there a way to convert - PDF to PPT - i know it sounds crazy - but that could be a possible solution. Everything u have would be a slide show

Comment: @Prasanna Thanks but I would like to avoid conversions: I want to know whether Adobe Acrobat Pro XI has this feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know it does not support scroll page by page., but if you want to increase the speed of scrolling you can use numbers (1...9)

1- minimum speed.
.
.
9- Maximum speed

Even up/down arrows can be used to control the scroll speed.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Scrolling page by page makes only sense if the whole page is displayed. That usually means that the whole width of the page is visible as well.

In this case, you switch between pages pressing the  and  buttons. (note that in Acrobat/Reader version 9 and older, this worked, no matter how wide the page is; in the Acrobat X user interface messing around session, this capability got removed, and it works now only when the whole width of the document is visible in the window.

Now, if what you want to do is some kind of a slide show, you have that built in, by using the Full Screen mode. To configure it, you go to the Full Screen tab of the Acrobat/Reader Preferences, and, in particular, set the Advance every xx Seconds option, where xx is the number of seconds between page advances. To switch to Full Screen mode, you use  or . You would use these settings if you have control over the computer using for displaying it.

If you distribute the document, you can control the Full Screen settings using Acrobat JavaScript. For your options, look at the fs Object description in the Acrobat JavaScript documentation.

If you do not work in Full Screen, you can set up an interval object, which calls a function to increase the page number (a function, because you will have to take care of the case when you hit the last page, and that is easier to program in a function than in the executable string of the setInterval() method).

So, the short answer is, Yes, you can auto-scroll page by page, if you are aware of what you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

It IS possible.

You should go to: `View` -> `Change Display`, as shown in your image. Then check the `Single page view` option listed, and then your scroll wheel will cycle through on a page by page basis.